# JavaScript async non-blocking functions without process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I read some questions about this topic here at stackoverflow but none of them seems to answer my doubts.

I know how to create async functions using [process.nextTick](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback):

```
var async_function = function(val, callback){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        callback(val);
    });
};
```

I've also read about [Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296505/understanding-promises-in-node-js), but how do you write async non-blocking functions without using libraries such as process, Promise, etc?

What's the native way? I thought first on this approach:

```
var async = function(val, cb) {
    cb(val);    
}
```

However, that function blocks:

```
async(3, function(val) {
    console.log(val);
});
console.log(4);
// returns:
3
4
```

So what's the correct implementation? How could I write async functions without depending on those libraries?

Comment: I know you really don't want an API, but I recently stumbled upon this video on reactive extensions for javascript, and found it fascinating. Why reinvent the wheel? http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/codefest/DC2010T0100-Keynote-Rx-curing-your-asynchronous-programming-blues

Comment: Keep in mind that "async" and "non-blocking" are not the same thing. By following the instructions in these answers (`process.nextTick`, `setTimeout`, etc) the callback will fire asynchronously, but once it starts running, it will still be blocking the event loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Node.js, you need to be using `process.nextTick`. In the browser, you can use the `postMessage` hack which is much more efficient than `setTimeout(function(){},0)`.

Here is a cross-browser implementation of the `postMessage` hack: https://github.com/timoxley/next-tick/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` - it's native function like a delay.

Comment: It's worth noting that, if you're only targeting Node.js, `process.nextTick(func)` is much more efficient than `setTimeout(func, 0)` and do, for most practical purposes, the exact same thing. See http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback

Comment: Thank you. You are right, but the question was - how to do async function on pure js.

Comment: Definitely! The comment was for other readers, not for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Break up your function's work into chunks and use [`process.nextTick`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) to queue the next chunk once the current one has completed.  That way you allow other queued callbacks to be executed between each chunk of work.  When all chunks have completed, call the callback that was passed into your function as a parameter.

The above is assuming your function is not calling existing async APIs which would naturally make your function async without doing anything special.