# understanding node.js callback structure

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am working on really simple node.js projects to better understand its callback functioning.

Suppose I have a login "system" like this one here:

```
if( req.query["username"] == "john" && req.query["password"] == "smith" )   {
    req.session.gatekeeper = req.query["username"];
    res.end( "succesfully logged in" );
} else { res.end( "wrong username or password" ); }
```

so far, so easy. Now suppose that instead of simply having "john:smith", I'd have it stored on redis. With PHP I'd have done it this way:

```
if( $r->get("$usernameIn") == $passwordIn ) {
  $_SESSION['gatekeeper'] = $usernameIn;
  echo "succesfully logged in";
}
```

but now, by having a look at the redis documentation (https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/) for node, I see that the get command is like this:

```
client.get("foo", function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```

It is really complicated for me to understand how to "structure" the first code I provided with this last one.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want your redis query to fit in with your first code? What value are you putting (or intending to put in) `foo`?

Comment: yes. in "foo" I'd like to put req.query["username"]

Comment: in the value referenced by that key in redis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly everything in node.js is asynchronous.  So, nearly every method that is called, you must specify a callback method to handle the result of the method call.  Normally, the callback function takes two parameters: error, result.  So it is up to you to check for the error and then handle the result.  There are other node modules that will allow for cleaner code ([node promises](https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise)), but that is out of scope for your question.

As a disclaimer I have not used redis before, so my code example below is based on your code example from above and a quick overview of the `redis` node.js module.

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.on("connect", function () {
    client.get(userName, function(err,returnedPassword){

      if(password === returnedPassword) {
        req.session.gatekeeper = req.query["username"];
        res.end( "succesfully logged in" );
      } else {
        res.end( "wrong username or password" );
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: cool, thank you! it's still a bit hard to mentally enter in this async state, coming from php. anyway, you should have a look at redis, it goes like bread and butter with node.js

Comment: Personally, I think the callbacks are a little difficult to read when you have multiple in a row.  I really like promises.  I normally use https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise.  Here is a link of stackoverflow people talking about them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296505/understanding-promises-in-node-js