# How to migrate old synchronous server-side javascript to node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I have to deal with large amounts of code developed in an old technology : Netscape IWS server side javascript (SSJS). I realized that with a few tricks and automatic conversions you can make the SSJS code work in Node.js almost unchanged. 
The problem I am having is that SSJS queries to the database are written in a synchronous style:

```
var cursor=database.cursor(sqlRequest);
while(cursor.next())
    {
    //do the stuff
    }
```

The solution I would like to try is to declare prototypes for `database` and `cursor` SSJS native objects and to mimic their behavior with node-mysql :

```
function Database() {
    // initialize database connection
}
Database.prototype.cursor = function(sqlRequest) {
  //here is the difficult part: how to access the query result
  //without providing a callback function ?
  return new Cursor(data);
};
function Cursor(data) {...}
Cursor.prototype.next = function() {..};
global.database= new Database();
```

You see that in order to write the body of the `Database.cursor` function I should get to use `connection.query` in a synchronous way.
I know that the topic was discussed many times ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597493/synchronous-database-queries-with-node-js), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982788/nodejs-asynchronous-database-function-needs-synchronous-answer) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842256/how-can-i-wrap-up-an-asynchronous-call-to-behave-synchronously)) and that it is not a good idea to force nodejs to behave synchronously but in my case it would save a huge refactoring of existing code...

Comment: ES6 generators + continuation library like https://github.com/visionmedia/co ?

Comment: Great idea. I will explore this approach.