# Unable to call functions with Require.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

i try to write an module for my node.js server with require.js that just returns the object i want to get from an url. But somehow i can't return the values i get with my method. The http.get... is performed after i return the value, so that i just get "undefined" but why?

Could you please help me? Sorry if that is an stupid questen but im really new to javascript node.js and require.js.

```
define(['http'], function(http){
    console.log('Hi ich bin pullArchiveVolume');

    var response = 1;
    console.log('Log 1: ' + response);

    http.get("http:...", function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {

            console.log("Log 2: " + response);
            response = 2;
            console.log("Log 3: " + response);

            response = JSON.parse(body);
            return response;
            // console.log("Log 2 :", response);
            // console.log("Got response: ", response);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });

    console.log("Log 4: " + response);
    return response;

})
```

Console Output:

```
Hi ich bin pullArchiveVolume
Log 1: 1
log 4: 1
log 2: 1
log 3: 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need to use a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a function that makes an async call just return something (unless it's a [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296505/understanding-promises-in-node-js)).

You need to have your function take a callback parameter:

```
function foo(callback) {
  doSomethingAsync(function(data) {
    // fire callback, which is a function that takes an argument 'data'
    callback(data)
  });
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
foo(function(data) {
  doStuffWith(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but how can i return the object and call this in another module?

Comment: You will just need to return a function that takes a callback instead of an object that holds a result. Instead of doing `return response` you'll have to wrap your logic in a function, like I showed, and return that function instead: `return foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason **why** you get what you get is that `http.get(...)` only *initiates* a network operation. At some indefinite point in the future the callbacks you gave to it will be executed. However, `http.get(...)` returns right away, *before* its callbacks are run. (Hence, it is an asynchronous operation). So by the time you hit your `return` statement the network operation is not complete yet and you return the initial value you gave to your `response` variable. Eventually, the network operation completes, your success callback is called and *then* you update `response` to the value you really wanted.

As others have said, you need to use callbacks or promises. Or rethink your design.