# How do I use mocha to do asynchronous tests using 'done();'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm working on trying to write an `asynchronous` test with `mocha` using the `done();` call. This is my code so far.

```
it('should have data.', function () {
    db.put(collection, key, json_payload)
        .then(function (result) {
            result.should.exist;
            done();
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            err.should.not.exist;
            done();
        })
})
```

The result however is that the code just executes **without waiting** for the then or fail to actually return with a result. Does `done();` need to be at a different place within the code?

Also posted the whole repo right here: https://github.com/Adron/node_testing_testing

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the function you pass to `it` call need to have the `done` parameter?  `it('should have data.', function(done) {` vs. `it('should have data.', function() {`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing asynchronous function with mocha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159846/testing-asynchronous-function-with-mocha)

Comment: @juanpaco yes, check out the answer below by notmyself.

Comment: if the tests executes "without waiting" doesn't mean it is asynchronous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want an async test you need to handle the done parameter

```
it('should have data.', function (done) {
    db.put(collection, key, json_payload)
        .then(function (result) {
            result.should.exist;
            done();
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            err.should.not.exist;
            done();
        })
})
```

also if you are using Q as your promise library you might want to complete your chain like so.

```
it('should have data.', function (done) {
    db.put(collection, key, json_payload)
        .then(function (result) {
            result.should.exist;
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            err.should.not.exist;

        })
        .done(done,done)
})
```

Comment: Tried both... I'm still not getting anything out of .then or .fail.  :-/

Comment: Added the full repo so you could give it a go. Put EVERYTHING in it. Including the Webstorm .idea directory. It's just a few bits of code. No idea what I'm actually doing here.  :-/

Comment: Oh wait, I see where ... oh man, my brain is twisted now. I'm gonna get this Javascript stuff yet.  ;)

The first time I'd tried it I missed the 'done' that is passed into the callback. It's kind of important!

Comment: what am I missing here? using done it makes it wait, does synchronous test, not asynchronous test.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to actually call the `done()` callback.

```
it('should have data.', function () {
    db.put(collection, key, json_payload)
        .then(function (result) {
            result.should.exist;
            done();
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            err.should.not.exist;
            done();
        })
})
```

Comment: Fixed the (), it just got left in the code I pasted above. However that didn't seem to fix the problem.  :(

Comment: Added the full repo so you could give it a go. Put EVERYTHING in it. Including the Webstorm .idea directory. It's just a few bits of code. No idea what I'm actually doing here.  :-/