# How to return a true or false after HTTP request in an angularJS function

Tags: angular, http

**Enviroment**
AngularJS 4

I try to run a HTTP Request in a function, but i can not send the result back.
Beloow have post my code with some comments.
I just need the `true` or `false` value but i receive nothing.

I struggling with this issue for a while and don't find a explaination and solution. Does someone can give me a hint?

```
public runLoginProcess(username:String, password:String):boolean{

    let body= { "username":username,"password":password };
    let head = new Headers();
    head.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    head.append("Accept", "application/json");

// RUN THE HTTP CALL AN IF IT WORKS, SEND TRUE AND ERROR IN CASE OF AN ERROR BACK
    this.http.post("<PATH TO MY SERVICE>", body)
      .subscribe(response => {
          let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
          if (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({"username": username, "token": token}))
            return true;
          }
        },
        error2 => {
          return false;
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js promises, async, or just callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133942/node-js-promises-async-or-just-callbacks). You have to use some sort of async construct: callbacks, pomises, or now await.

Comment: Are you expecting runLoginProcess to return the true/false result? I suspect you're expecting a synchronous behaviour from an inherently asynchronous function. Try using your debugger, or try putting a console.log right after your call to http.post, and also put a console.log call right before your return true/return false statements. Perhaps put a delay in your HTTP service if you control it. Then observe the order of execution.

Comment: This is Angular, not AngularJS. There's no such thing as AngularJS 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach to observables is all off.  your runLoginProcess function isn't returning anything, and the subscribe function shouldn't return at all.  The way you should use this is more like

```js
public runLoginProcess(username:String, password:String):Observable<boolean>{

    let body= { "username":username,"password":password };
    let head = new Headers();
    head.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    head.append("Accept", "application/json");

// RUN THE HTTP CALL AN IF IT WORKS, SEND TRUE AND ERROR IN CASE OF AN ERROR BACK
    return this.http.post("<PATH TO MY SERVICE>", body)
      .map(response => {
          let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
          if (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({"username": username, "token": token}))
            return true;
          } else {
             return false;
          }
        }
      )
      .catch(err => Observable.of(false)); //this line isn't needed, but just if you don't want to error handle at the caller's subscription, you can intercept them here and map to a false value.
  }
  
  
  
  var loggedIn;
  
   this.runLoginProcess().subscribe(
      (val) => this.loggedIn = val
    );
```

This way, you take the response from your post, map it into a boolean value, return that observable sequence to the caller, then the caller subscribes to the observable and receives the boolean value in the subscription.

Remember observables are just a definition of how to handle a stream of values.

Comment: thank you for your very fast reply,  but i am facing to the problem, that http.post() has no map, just a  subscribe()

Comment: you need to either import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; or import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; the angular4 http client returns observables which always have a map method.  If you're using a custom http client, then that is a separate issue.

Comment: Observable is added to this class

Comment: then there is some other issue, either you're overriding the http service somewhere or there is an issue with your compiler.  The http client always returns observables which always have a map method.  Did you change the function return type to be Observable<boolean>? and are you returning the http method exactly as I wrote it?