# NodeJs: Wait for ForEach function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I write a validate function where I want to check if a array is valid to be instert. I want to return multiple errors.
I searched for that topic but couldnt get it runnig with promises, async-module.
Im very new to NodeJS and would be very grateful if you could help me.

```
function validateNewResultUnits(sets, req) {
  var validate = [];
  sets.forEach(function(setItem) {
    setItem.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.hasOwnProperty("name") == false) {
        validate.push({
          'name': 'Name has to be set'
        });
      } else {
        if (item.name === "" || item.name === null || item.name === undefined) {
          validate.push({
            'name': 'Name cannot be empty'
          });
        } else {
          Exercise.forge({
            name: req.body.name
          }).fetch({
            withRelated: [{
              'resultUnits': function(qb) {
                qb.where('name', item.name);
              }
            }]
          }).then(function(exercise) {
            console.log("Länge:" + exercise.related('resultUnits').length);
            if (exercise.related('resultUnits').length === 0)
              validate.push({
                'name': 'ResultUnit not found'
              });
          }).catch(function(error) {
            validate.push({
              'name': 'An Error occured'
            });
          });
        }
      }

      if (item.hasOwnProperty("value") == false) {
        validate.push({
          'value': 'Value has to be set'
        });
      } else {
        if (item.value === "" || item.value === null || item.value === undefined) {
          validate.push({
            'value': 'Name cannot be empty'
          });
        } else {
          if (isNaN(item.value)) validate.push({
            'value': 'Value has to be number'
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
  return validate;
}

var validate = validateNewResultUnits(req.body.sets, req);
console.log(validate);
if (validate.length == 0) {
  // ...
}
```

The `console.log(validate);` return undefined before the function is ready to return something.
Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
Promise Attempt (inside the second forEach)

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
                                Exercise.forge({name: req.body.name })
                                .fetch({
                                    withRelated: [{'resultUnits': function(qb) {
                                        qb.where('name',item.name)
                                    }}]
                                }).then(function(exercise) { 
                                console.log("Länge:"+exercise.related('resultUnits').length);
                                if (exercise.related('resultUnits').length === 0)
                                    resolve({'name':'ResultUnit not found'});
                                }).catch(function(error) { resolve({'name': 'An Error occured'}); });
                            });
                            promise.then(function(result) {
                                validate.push(result);
                            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `Exercise.forge({name: req.body.name }).fetch(...)` as it runs asynchronously which makes the `validateNewResultUnits` function continues its execution till it returns undefined result.

I would suggest that you change that code to embrace promises instead of those ugly async callbacks, that will require changes in the `validateNewResultUnits` function itself and any of its callers. Here is some resources that will help you understand promises very quickly:

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/

[Understanding promises in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296505/understanding-promises-in-node-js)

http://howtonode.org/promises

https://vimeo.com/144550711

https://vimeo.com/144550811

https://vimeo.com/144550913

---

**EDIT**

Here is a copy of the provided code but using promises instead

```
function validateNewResultUnits(sets, req) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var validate = [];
    var internalPromises = [];
    sets.forEach(function(setItem) {
      setItem.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty("name") == false) {
          validate.push({'name': 'Name has to be set'});
        } else {
          if (item.name === "" || item.name === null || item.name === undefined) {
            validate.push({'name': 'Name cannot be empty'});
          } else {
            var internalPromise = Exercise.forge({name: req.body.name}).fetch({
                withRelated: [{
                  'resultUnits': function (qb) {
                    qb.where('name', item.name);
                  }
                }]
              });
            internalPromise.then(function(exercise) {
              console.log("Länge:" + exercise.related('resultUnits').length);
              if (exercise.related('resultUnits').length === 0)
                validate.push({'name': 'ResultUnit not found'});
            }).catch(function(error) {
              validate.push({'name': 'An Error occured'});
            });
            internalPromises.push(internalPromise);
          }
        }

        if (item.hasOwnProperty("value") == false) {
          validate.push({'value': 'Value has to be set'});
        } else {
          if (item.value === "" || item.value === null || item.value === undefined) {
            validate.push({'value': 'Name cannot be empty'});
          } else {
            if (isNaN(item.value))
              validate.push({'value': 'Value has to be number'});
          }
        }
      });
    });

    if(internalPromises && internalPromises.length) {
      Promise.all(internalPromises).then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        resolve(validate);
      }, function (reason) {
        console.log(reason);
        resolve(validate);
      });
    } else {
      resolve(validate);
    }
  });
}

var validatePromise = validateNewResultUnits(req.body.sets, req);
validatePromise.then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
  if (result.length == 0) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: So if i use bluebird to make the `Exercise.forge...` promising the function would be sync?

Comment: It won't make it sync, but it will return a promise to the caller, and the caller can attach a `.then(function(){...})` which will be called when the promise gets resolved or rejected, something like this:
``var promise = asyncFetch();
    promise.then(function success(result) {}, function error(error) {});``

Comment: If you're using nodejs, you don't need bluebird for basic Promise, it's already included.

Comment: @ShanShan Bluebird has nice utility functions however, such as `filter`, `map`, `mapSeries` and `each`, which could be useful here in replacing the `forEach` loop

Comment: Okay. But my question. If i wrap the `Exercise.forge..` into a promise. Will it work that the forEach will wait?

Comment: I don't think so because you need to handle that promise in the caller, I think you need to try that out and let us know the results.

Comment: As I said before, the promise should be handled by the caller, i.e. who is calling the `validateNewResultUnits` function. So your `validateNewResultUnits` should return a promise, and the `validateNewResultUnits` caller handles that returning promise.

Comment: Okay got it. But how do i do this..? :/

Comment: I will try to do that for you in a minute using the code you have submitted so far

Comment: Wow that would be so awesome!

Comment: Right now I´m in the mood to say i love you. hahaha :D