# How to use loops in promises

Tags: node.js, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to execute a for loop within a promise with no success, i think my issue has to do with where to call resolve but i'm not sure

```js
/*
* Get conversations of user
* @param user {String}
*/
function getConversations(user){
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  var conversations = user.Conversations
  var newConversations = []
  for(var conversation of conversations) {
   helperGetConvo(conversation.ConversID).then(function(convo){
    newConversations.push(createConversationObject({messages:[], name:convo.conversationName, users:["broulaye", "doumbia"], Id:convo.conversationID}))


   }).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log("failure when finding conversation 2: " + reason)
   })

  }
  resolve(newConversations)



 })
}


function helperGetConvo(convoId) {
 return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
  query.findConversation(convoId).then(function(convers) {

   if(convers) {
    console.log("conversation was found: " + convers)
   }
   else {
    console.log("conversation was not found: " + convers)
   }
   resolve(convers)
  }).catch(function(reason) {
   console.log("failure when finding conversation: " + reason)
  })


 })
}
```

when I execute my code like this the getConversations function only returns an empty array. but when i change the getConversations function like so:

```js
function getConversations(user){
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  var conversations = user.Conversations
  var newConversations = []
  for(var conversation of conversations) {
   helperGetConvo(conversation.ConversID).then(function(convo){
    newConversations.push(createConversationObject({messages:[], name:convo.conversationName, users:["broulaye", "doumbia"], Id:convo.conversationID}))
    resolve(newConversations)

   }).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log("failure when finding conversation 2: " + reason)
   })

  }
 })
}
```

i do get an output, however it does not get through the whole forloop i believe because from my understanding resolve work like a return statement.

someone help plz

Comment: You have to wait for the promises to resolve, take a look at Promise.all. I'd also advise some more reading on promises, your code is really messed up.

Comment: avoid the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all`

```
function getConversations(user){
    var conversations = user.Conversations
    var promises = conversations.map(c=>helperGetConvo(c.ConversID))

    return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(data=>{
            let newConversations = data.map(convo=>{
                return createConversationObject({messages:[], name:convo.conversationName, users:["broulaye", "doumbia"], Id:convo.conversationID})
            })
            return newConversations
        })
        .catch(reason=>{
            console.log("failure when finding conversation: " + reason)
        })
}
```

Use the function like so

```
getConversations(user).then(newConversations=>{
    //your code
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to collect the promises in an array using map instead of for-in.  Then use Promise.all() to wait for all of them to resolve (or one to reject).

Something like:

```
return Promise.all(conversations.map(conversation => {
    return helperGetConvo(...).then().catch();
}
```

Remember all promises MUST either resolve or reject.  If you don't follow this rule you get into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call `resolve` you are resolving the entire promise.  The for loop does not wait for each `helperGetConvo()` call to finish before moving on to the next one.  Whichever of those promises hits the `then` statement first will call `resolve` and that's what your outer promise will resolve to.

You can read more on promises at: [Understanding promises in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296505/understanding-promises-in-node-js).

If you want to wait for a group of promises to finish, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).  It takes in a list of promises, and will only resolve if all promises complete successfully.

```
function getConversations(user) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var conversations = user.Conversations;
    var newConversations = [];
    //create a list of promises
    var promises = [];
    for (var conversation of conversations) {
      // push each promise into our array
      promises.push(
        helperGetConvo(conversation.ConversID).then(function (convo) {
          newConversations.push(createConversationObject({
            messages: [],
            name: convo.conversationName,
            users: ['broulaye', 'doumbia'],
            Id: convo.conversationID
          }));
        }).catch(function (reason) {
          console.log('failure when finding conversation 2: ' + reason);
        })
      );

    }
    // wait for all promises to complete
    // when then do, resolve the newConversations variable
    // which will now have all of the conversation objects that we wanted to create
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => resolve(newConversations)).catch(reject);
  });
}
```

You could also use async/await to clean this up.  Async/await provides some nice syntactic sugar for removing the need to do `return new Promise(...)`.  This next code snippet is not the best way to use async/await because the for loop will process everything synchronously (one conversation at a time).  This blog post has been hugely helpful for my understanding of using async/await in iterative problems: https://blog.lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795.

```
async function getConversations(user) {
    var conversations = user.Conversations;
    var newConversations = [];

    // process each converstaion in sequence
    for (var conversation of conversations) {
      // instead of doing .then() we can use await
      // convo will have the result from the helperGetConvo
      // we put it in a try/catch because  output
      // we still want to have the error if something fails
      try {
        var convo = await helperGetConvo(conversation.ConversID);
        newConversations.push(createConversationObject({
          messages: [],
          name: convo.conversationName,
          users: ['broulaye', 'doumbia'],
          Id: convo.conversationID
        }));
      } catch(reason) {
        console.log('failure when finding conversation 2: ' + reason);
      }
    }

  // return
  return newConversations;
}
```

Async functions return promises.  So you can call this function by doing `getConversations(user).then(...)`.  But I think async/await makes your code look much cleaner.  There are definitely further optimizations that you can do, but hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: You're creating unnecessary promises i think. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern

Comment: Probably.  I was trying to leave as much of the OP's original code as possible and show how he could leverage `Promise.all` within that structure.  If I could chose, I would have changed this all to be async/await to clean it up.

Comment: @EricGuan yea i'm probably am, i'm not really too familiar with this that's why.

Comment: @TheF1rstPancake I'm not familiar with async/await how would you use that to clean this up? i try using it once and everything crashed so i switched back to this

Answer (score 1):

You can loop a promise within a helper function that I found when I was trying to address a similar issue.  I use this method to loop promises as it will not fall over at the first rejected promise.  Instead I can handle the resolve or reject and return the final result once the loop has finished.  The Promise in the code snippet below is using bluebird, http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

```
    function promiseWhile(condition, action) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            var loop = () => {
                if (!condition()) return resolve();
                return Promise.cast(action())
                    .then(loop)
                    .catch(reject);
            };

            process.nextTick(loop);
            return resolve;
        })
    }
```

I modified your code examples provided with some dummy data and got it to work with the helper function.  As a result I believe your getConversations function would look like this:

```
    function getConversations(user) {
        var conversations = user.Conversations;
        var newConversations = [];

        var stop = conversations.length;
        var index = 0

        //loop promise
        return promiseWhile(() => {
            // Condition for stopping
            return index < stop;
        }, () => {
            // Action to run, should return a promise
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                helperGetConvo(conversations[index].ConversID)
                    .then(function(convo) {
                            newConversations.push(createConversationObject({
                            messages: [],
                            name: convo.conversationName,
                            users: ['broulaye', 'doumbia'],
                            Id: convo.conversationID
                            }));
                            index++;
                            resolve();
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                           console.log('failure when finding conversation: ' + error);
                           index++;
                           resolve();
                        });
            })
        })
            //This will execute when loop ends
            .then(() => {
                return newConversations;
            });
    }
```

Hope this helps.